# verbose stack Exit status 1 at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16) Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, docker, npm, angular-cli

While running Dockerfile of a legacy angular application seeing below issue
[image]

This application is up and running in STAGE environment

**log file:**

[image]

**package.json**

[image]

**Docker File:**

[image]

Comment: looks like there is a problem with your docker file/conatiner can you share your docker file just want to know "WORKDIR" and all "CD" commands in docker file.

Comment: @shashanksharma added docker file also

Comment: your docker file looks fine. you can go inside your running container to see does file copied successfully or not by "docker exec -it <container_id> bash". as your error is "project  not found" means either files not copied or running "npm start" somewhere else.

Comment: also your workdir is "root/app" but you are copying service.ts file in "root/src/app/config/"

Comment: @Storytellerr when I update versions to higher getting different issue. I don't think issue with location.